# navbar mobile view not closing after click Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design, menu, navbar

I have this navbar. But in mobile view with the menu collapsed there is a problem that once I click on the hamburger icon to open the menu, the menu does not close when clicking on a item. I use the menu on a onepage website link to class id. Tried about ten suggestions that I found but nothing is working.

Is there somebody that really knows what is causing this? I use Bootstrap 5.3.2

Here is my navbar:

`

```
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand logo7z" href="http://www.zevenzorg.nl">
            <img src="images/7z-icon.png" alt="Bootstrap" width="60px" height="60px">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03" toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#overons">Over ons</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#samen">Samen</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#vacatures">Vacatures</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          <div>
        </div>
      </nav>`
```

Tried javascript, checked collapse code. All did not work.

WORKAROUND:
I discovered a workaround to change the #home link with the complete url like:

```
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="http://www.mywebsite.nl/#home">Home</a>
```

By doing this the browser loads the page again what wil close the collapse menu